# Merging data.tables by numeric column when machine tolerance needs to be accounted for

Tags: r, data.table

Many have seen the issue with using `==` to compare to floating point
numbers. `==` fails to return `TRUE` but `all.equal` works.

```r
x <- sqrt(2)
x^2 == 2
#> [1] FALSE
all.equal(x^2, 2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

My issue comes from the need to join to `data.table`s by a numeric column
where `==` will fail to find the matching pairs.

I have considered coercing the numeric values to characters, but that option
has too many other potiential errors. I have considered rounding the values,
but that to, in the application I need, will create more problems.

Here is simple example of a join that is failing because
`DT1$x == DT2$x` will return `FALSE` when it would be preferable to have the
return be `TRUE`.

```r
library(data.table)
packageVersion("data.table")
#> [1] '1.12.8'

DT1 <- data.table(x = sqrt(1:10), v1 = 1:10)
DT2 <- data.table(x = 1:10, v2 = LETTERS[1:10])

# set x to its square
DT1[, x := x^2]

# left join
merge(DT1, DT2, by = "x", all.x = TRUE)
#>      x v1   v2
#>  1:  1  1    A
#>  2:  2  2 <NA>
#>  3:  3  3 <NA>
#>  4:  4  4    D
#>  5:  5  5 <NA>
#>  6:  6  6 <NA>
#>  7:  7  7 <NA>
#>  8:  8  8 <NA>
#>  9:  9  9    I
#> 10: 10 10 <NA>
```

How can I specify a left join by a numeric column key such that the machine
tolerance in the comparison is accounted for?
<sup>Created on 2020-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: By the way, I welcome tidyverse solutions in general, but the specific problem I'm working requires a data.table solution.

Comment: Does your real data actually use floating point numbers? In this case you could `round()` the data and cast to integers before matching. But in general trying to join on continuous values doesn't seem like a good idea. Are your continuous variables really categorical variables?

Comment: @MrFlick, your comment was extremely helpful.  Technically yes, continuous values are presented in one table, are rounded to a given precision and then joined with a look up table.  I had forgotten/overlooked casting the rounded values to integers; they were still numeric.  Casting to integers solved the issue I was having.  I suppose the example posted in the question wasn't so good for describing the actual issue I was working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `roll = "nearest"`. Note that only the last column specified in `on =` can be rolling.

```
library(data.table)
DT1[DT2,on = "x", roll = "nearest"]
    x v1 v2
 1:  1  1  A
 2:  2  2  B
 3:  3  3  C
 4:  4  4  D
 5:  5  5  E
 6:  6  6  F
 7:  7  7  G
 8:  8  8  H
 9:  9  9  I
10: 10 10  J
```

I suspect the problem is more complicated than this simple case, but you could subsequently filter joins that do not meet a certain threshold of difference.

**Data**

```
DT1 <- data.table(x = sqrt(1:10), v1 = 1:10)
DT2 <- data.table(x = 1:10, v2 = LETTERS[1:10])
DT1[, x := x^2]
```